# AngularJS - Use ng-repeat to print inputs based off of a number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

New to AngularJS and have question on how to use the ng-repeat.

Currently I can only find examples where you read from a service, and then ng-repeat loops over that.

My situation is a admin can create an invitation for guests and set a property called:

```
total_in_party = 4;
```

Now based off of "total_in_party" I want to 3 input fields, for each guest in the party

Like:

```
<div ng-repeat="guest in party">
  <input type="text" ng-model="guest.first_name" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="guest.last_name" />
  <select ng-model="selectedGuestMeal" ng-options="meal.id as meal.name for meal in meals"></select>
</div>
```

For this case, it should print those 3 input fields 4 times.

I think I am close, just need to know how to create the party object if I have no data stored in it yet?

If I am doing this completely wrong - don't hesitate to inform me!

Answer (score 3):

I had to solve this exact problem recently. You essentially need to create an array of guest objects in your scope and then bind the array to a form using `ng-repeat`.

See a working demo of my solution here: http://plnkr.co/edit/2aYSLYe0IcRGXR7Lm0HR?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.numberOfGuests = 1;
  $scope.guests = [];

  addGuests($scope.numberOfGuests);

  // When the number of guests changes, we want to repopulate the
  // array of guest info (in a non-destructive manner).
  $scope.$watch('numberOfGuests', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (!newValue) {
      return;
    }

    newValue = parseInt(newValue, 10);
    oldValue = parseInt(oldValue, 10);

    // If the number of guests increased, add some empty objects to the array.
    if (!isNaN(oldValue) && newValue > oldValue) {
      var numberOfGuests = newValue - oldValue;
      addGuests(numberOfGuests);
    } else {
      // Otherwise reset length of array
      $scope.guests.length = newValue;
    }
  });

  function addGuests(numberToAdd) {
    if (!isNaN(numberToAdd) && numberToAdd > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < numberToAdd; i++) {
        $scope.guests.push({});
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here's the view

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form>
    <p>Nunmber of Guests <input type="number" ng-model="numberOfGuests" ></p>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="guest in guests track by $index">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="guest.name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="guest.email"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <pre>{{guests | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! Although this does more than my current needs it's going to be very helpful going forward!

Comment: I'm curios why you use $scope.$watch instead of an onchange event.  It seems more intuitive to me to be able to look at the HTML and see an onchange attached than to notice a $watch in the controller. I'm still quite new to Angular, so please let me know if I'm missing something or if it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: @Darryl the `ng-change` directive will only fire when the `onchange` event for that html element is fired, not when the underlying model changes. I wanted my solution to work regardless of how `numberOfGuests` was modified.  See this example:  http://plnkr.co/edit/ECZghdmvuHcQNi35Qmol?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate a `guests` property on $scope, in the controller based on `total_in_party`;

```
function initGuests(totalInParty) {
  $scope.guests = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < totalInParty; i++) {
    $scope.guests[i] = {
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      meal: ''
    };
  }
}
```

in your `ng-repeat` make use of `$index`, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="guest in guests">
  <input type="text" ng-model="guests[$index].first_name" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="guests[$index].last_name" />
  <select ng-model="guests[$index].meal" ng-options="meal.id as meal.name for meal in meals"></select>
</div>
```

Did not tested it, but it should work :)

Comment: Thanks Tamas, exactly what I needed! Can you give me a breakdown on whats going on with the $index? I am going to be saving each first_name last_name and meal as it's own row.

Comment: `$index` is simply an iterator, for each step in the repeat it is incremented automatically: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat.

Comment: Perfect, I just found that link!

Answer (score 1):

You can watch the `total_in_party` number and add/subtract guests based off of it

**JS**

```
$scope.$watch('total_in_party', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue != null) {
    console.log(newValue, oldValue);
    if (newValue > oldValue) { //add
      var i = newValue - oldValue;
      for (var k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        $scope.party.push({
          first_name: "",
          last_name: "",
          selectedGuestMeal: null
        });
      }
    } else if (newValue < oldValue) { //subtract
      var i = oldValue - newValue;
      $scope.party.splice(0, i);
    }
  }
});
```

[see this plunkr for example](http://plnkr.co/edit/n97uruw2qVttmpod74He?p=preview)

Comment: this solution will also work alongside an init function, e.g. the one @tamas-pap suggested. Where is your initial total_in_party value coming from? The server? A http call? Or do you have it in your view on page load?

Comment: An admin creates a invitation specifying the total_in_party which is just the sum of (invitee + guests), an association is made between the invitation on the invitee.

I am now working on the invitee end - where the invitee logs in, and based on total_in_party I create Name/Meal/RSVP fields for them & their guests.

I have this hooked up to a ROR install, so I am receiving all my data through JSON.

Comment: Ok, either way, when total_in_party comes from the server, you can set that value on your controller and angular should add the correct amount of fields for you using my $watch above